# Unity UI double sided image

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to create an image in Unity UI system that has different colors on both sides. Such as when I rotate it 180 degrees it looks different.

I experimented with two images with a single parent and then rotating the parent.
It didn't really work even with an addition of canvas components or changing "z" axis.

The only solution I could find is to change their sorting layer mid-rotate but I really want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parent object like you mentioned, place the two images under it. 
Create two materials and add the following single face shader:

```
Shader "GUI/3D Text Shader - Cull Back" 
{ 
    Properties{ 
        _MainTex("Font Texture", 2D) = "white" {} 
        _Color("Text Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
    }
    SubShader
    { 
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" } 
        Lighting Off Cull Back ZWrite Off Fog{ Mode Off } 
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 
            Pass
            { 
                Color[_Color] 
                SetTexture[_MainTex]
                { 
                    combine primary, texture * primary 
                } 
            } 
    } 
}
```

Assign both materials to each image. Flip one of the image by 180 degrees on the y axis. 
Then you should be able to rotate the parent to create the flip effect.

Credit to:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/310203/1-way-text-mesh.html

Comment: If you are suggesting a shader, you can just draw it all in one shader for both sides tho. (normal direction and - normal direction)

Answer (score 1):

Old but may help some one else; this solution is for a 3D `GameObject` image; and the logic can be applied to a UI image

Steps:

1. Create `GameObject`
2. Create a couple of `Quad` objects as children of the brand new `GameObject`
3. Drag/Drop each individual image onto relevant `Quad`
4. For the quad that you want its image to be reversed, set its axis (whatever access you want to -180), and leave the other quad non-rotated
   Now you can rotate the parent `GameObject`, and both images will show;

My example is showing kind of waving flag

[image]